# how should you handle file open error in a thread without cancellation?

Tags: c++, multithreading, fopen

I have an service application that reads a config file containing a list of files to open. The problem is when it doesn't find the file in the directory, it throws an exception thus cancelling the thread and stopping the service application as well.

Here's a code block of the function being called in a thread:

```
FILE* file_;
ServiceApp::File::File( const char* filename, const char* mode) :
file_(fopen(filename, mode))
{
    if( !file_ )
    {
    // throwing will stop the service when file doesn't exist, what work around could we do?
    throw std::runtime_error("file open failure");
}
```

**Question:** 
How do we prevent this from happening so that when a file listed in the config file is not found in the directory, the application would just ignore it and continue with the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be just to try-catch your own exception, in the thread, then check for it being *that* exception (to ignore it), and rethrowing if it's some other exception.

I'm not sure if it's possible to add info to the exception where thrown or is it legacy code? In the latter case you'll have to resort to string comparison, which of course is ugly. Anyway.

```
// pseudo-code
while(GotFilesInQueue())
{
  try
  {
    LoadNextFile();
  }
  catch(std::exception& e)
  {
    if(!IgnoreExceptionPredicate(e))
    {
      throw;
    }
  }
}
```

[On Rethrowing](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.cbclx01/cplr153.htm)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `std::async`. If a function throws which is run via `std::async`, the exception will be saved in the `std::future`. I will be rethrown when you call `std::future::get()`. However if you don't do that, it will just be "ignored" and thus you application will keep on running.

Example:

```
auto lambda = [] {
    throw std::runtime_error("error");
};

auto handle = std::async(std::launch::async, lambda);
```

For more info on `std::async` read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).

Comment: is this only applicable to c++0x?

Comment: @Owen yes. boost probably works, too, if you can't use `c++11`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to put try / catch statements to surround the block of code that processes the file.
There is a high chance that you will encounter other exceptions being thrown in other special cases (e.g. when reading network file that disappeared during reading), so check code for other exceptions carefully